# Generate mp3 waveform, and pre-render for page load

Tags: javascript, php, waveform

I want to create the [waveform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform) of an mp3 file. I also want to pre-render the waveform, so it is ready to be displayed when the page loads.

```php
<?php
session_start();

include "DB.inc";

$xxid = $_POST['xxid'];
$sxxid = $_POST['sxxid'];

if(is_array($_FILES)) {

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userAudio']['tmp_name'])) {

        $sourcePath = $_FILES['userAudio']['tmp_name'];
        $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["userAudio"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = $_POST['sxxid'] . '.' .end($temp);
        $ext = end($temp);

        $common_path = "assets/$xxid";

        if (!is_dir($common_path)) {
            mkdir($common_path);
        }

        $common_path = "assets/$xxid/audio";

        if (!is_dir($common_path)) {
            mkdir($common_path);
        }

        $targetPath = $common_path.'/'.$newfilename;
        $web_common_path = SITE_LINK."/assets/$xxid/audio/";
        $web_targetPath = $web_common_path.$newfilename;

        $filename = array();
        $filename[0] = $common_path.$_POST['sxxid'].'.wav';
        $num_files = count($filename);

        for ($n=0; $n<$num_files; $n++) {
            if (file_exists($filename[$n])) {
                unlink ($filename[$n]);
            }
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
            $mp3 = $common_path.'/'.$_POST['sxxid'].'.mp3';
            shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $targetPath . ' '. $mp3);

            ?>

            <audio controls>
                <source src="<?php echo $web_targetPath."?dasasd=".mt_rand(0, 50000); ?>" type="audio/wav" />
            </audio>

        <?php

        } else {
            echo "Uploaded file can not be moved";  
        }
    } else {
        echo "Uploaded file not found";
    }
} else {
    echo "Uploaded not allowed";
}

?>
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: View [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293492/generating-mp3-waveform-with-php).